# Why I get a lot of unwanted output when I convert ByteBuffer to String?

Tags: java, nio

I write a UDP server to receive messages from clients using NIO:

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));
ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
buf.clear();
while (channel.receive(buf) != null) {
      System.out.println("---has received data:" + new String(buf.array(), ASCII));
      buf.clear();
}
```

then I use nc command to send some data to the UDP server

```
nc -u 127.0.0.1 9999 < ./test.txt
```

there is only one line in test.txt

```
#cat ./test.txt
12345678
```

and the output of the server is like this
[image]

so how could I get the 12345678 string and remove the following '口' things?

Comment: this works for me, didn't get any `[]` brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(9999));

ByteBuffer chunkData = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024);
chunkData.clear();

channel.receive(chunkData);

// remove unwanted data
byte[] validData = new byte[chunkData.position()];
System.arraycopy(chunkData.array(), 0, validData, 0, validData.length);

System.out.println("---has received data:" + new String(validData));
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not unwanted output, this is because you print the entirety of your Buffer.

`buf.clear();` does not clear the buffer with zeros, it just resets the position to 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("---has received data:" + new String(buf.array(), ASCII));
```

You're ignoring the datagram length. This should be:

```
System.out.println("---has received data:" + new String(buf.array(), 0, buf.position()-1, ASCII));
```